# Declaring and assigning a function object with object keys in one line

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to condense the following into a single statement?

```
var foo = function () { return; };
foo.bar = 'baz';
```

The closest I came was:

```
var foo = Object.create(function(){return;}, { bar : { value: 'baz' } });
```

But the function will not run.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to be "instantiating an object method with its object keys". `foo` isn't a method of anything.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make it into a single statement, but it's a bit hackish, so I don't know if it's worth showing how.

Comment: *"But the function will not run."* That's because `foo` is not a function. It's an object with a function as its prototype.

Comment: Well, since you're getting novel solutions anyway, here are a couple ways that are a single statement, though I wouldn't use them. `var foo=((foo=function(){}).bar="baz",foo);` or `var foo=[foo=function(){},foo.bar="baz"][0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a function that copies attributes from one object to another and returns the modified object. This is a feature of most general-purpose JS libraries, and it's usually called "extend".

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
var foo =       _.extend( function () { return; }, { bar: 'baz' } );
```

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
var foo =       $.extend( function () { return; }, { bar: 'baz' } );
```

[Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/):

```
var foo =  Object.extend( function () { return; }, { bar: 'baz' } );
```

[Angular](https://angularjs.org/):

```
var foo = angular.extend( function () { return; }, { bar: 'baz' } );
```

[Ext](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/):

```
var foo =      Ext.apply( function () { return; }, { bar: 'baz' } );
```

Comment: Is there a native equivalent to this extend? I'm guessing not.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt these libraries would provide it if there were a native function already.

Comment: The native equivalent is `Object.assign` which will be available in ES6.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple:

```
var foo = Object.defineProperty(function() { }, 'bar', {value: 'baz'});
```

Taking advantage of the fact that `Object.defineProperty` both accepts a function as its first argument, and returns the object.

Or if you happen to have a variable `x` lying around:

```
var foo = (x = function () { }, x.bar = 'baz', x);
```

#### Ridiculous hacks

My original answer to this question proposed the following, which could maybe be considered a "single statement":

```
var foo = (function() { var f = function () {} ; f.bar = 'baz'; return f; })();
```

Or, if you consider the following a "single statement":

```
for (var foo=function() {}; !foo.bar; foo.bar = 'baz') { }
```

Or, in the spirit of @cookiemonster:

```
var foo = (foo=function(){}) && (foo.bar = 'baz') && foo;
```

Comment: That looks like 4 statements to me.