# Setting properties on functions in JavaScript object literal notation

Tags: javascript

```
var api = {};

api.c = function () {return 1};
api.c.m = function () {return 2};

alert(api.c()); // returns 1
alert(api.c.m()); // returns 2

var api2 = {
    c: function () {}; // can't put m inside c in object literal notation
};
```

How would we embed m in c in object literal notation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring and assigning a function object with object keys in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098069/declaring-and-assigning-a-function-object-with-object-keys-in-one-line)

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so, please accept.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. However, you could do

```
Object.defineProperty(api.c, 'm', { value: function() { return 2; } });
```

Since `Object.defineProperty` returns the object, you could do

```
var api = {
    c: Object.defineProperty(function() { }, 'm', {
        value: function() { return 2; }
    })
};
```

Or for multiple properties:

```
var api = {
    c: Object.defineProperties(function() { }, {
        m: { value: function() { return 2; } },
        ...
    })
};
```

This may come closest to satisfying your desire to write the function properties in object literal form.

Or, you could use the `extend` feature available in most frameworks (or `Object.assign` in ES6):

```
var api = {
    c: Object.assign(function() { }, {
        m: function() { return 2; }
    )
};
```

Feel free to replace `Object.assign` with `$.extend`, `_.extend`, etc.

Depending on your tolerance for ugliness, you might try the following, a variation on @zerkms's proposal without the IIFE (you'll need a variable `x`):

```
var api = {
    c: (x = function() { }, x.m = function() { return 2; }, x)
};
```

Comment: really nice... Will be withholding the answer until later.

Answer (score 2):

It technically is possible, but it's ugly

```
var api2 = {
    c: (function() {
        var f = function() {};
        f.m = 'something else';

        return f;
    }())
};
```

So I personally don't see a good reason to do it that way instead of how you do it in the 1st case.